# why the value of /proc/$pid/comm is changed running tsan?

Tags: linux, proc

I compile program with `tsan(ThreadSanitizer)`, and running it. Besides I read `/proc/$pid/comm` of this process, expect the value is program's name. But I got "exe", why?

```bash
./my_program

root     25515   712  0 09:40 pts/1    00:00:00 my_program

cat /proc/25515/comm
exe
```

use `gcc 7.3.0`

I want to know what happened the value of comm file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is tsan re-exec program with name "exe". source code here
InitializePlatform. disable ASLR can fix this problem.